# LINQ syntax - ordering of criteria

Tags: linq

I'm trying to understand LINQ syntax and getting stuck.   So I've got this line which  gets all of the people with the postcode I'm searching for

```
IQueryable<int> PersonIDsWithThisPostcode = _context.Addresses
       .Where(pst => pst.Postcode.Contains(p))
       .Select(b => b.PersonID);
```

This line then only returns  people in PersonIDsWithThisPostcode

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID));
```

I'd have expected it to be something along the lines of this, where you're looking at a container, then checking against a subset of values to see what you want.

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.PersonID.Contains(PersonIDsWithThisPostcode));
```

So from a SQL point-of-view I'd think of it something like this

```
bucket = bucket.Where(bucket.Contains(listoffish));
```

but it seems to act like this

```
bucket = bucket.Where(listoffish.Contains(bucket));
```

I've read through lots of documentation but I can't get my head around this apparently simple notion.   Any help to explain this way of thinking would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `PersonID` is an `int` you can't use `ps.PersonID.Contains` because an int is not a collection (or string which would search a substring).

The only correct way is to search your `PersonId` in a collection which is the `PersonIDsWithThisPostcode`-query that returns all matching `PersonId`s.
A single `PersonID` doesn't contain a collection but a collection of `PersonId`s contains a single `PersonId`.

So this is correct, it returns all persons which `PersonId` is in the other sequence:

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID));
```

and this not:

```
persons = persons.Where(ps => ps.PersonID.Contains(PersonIDsWithThisPostcode));
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is reversed in comparison to SQL, which should come as no surprise, considering that C# and SQL are two different languages.

In SQL you place the list on the right, because `IN` operator reads "item **in** collection"

```
WHERE someId IN (100, 102, 113, 200, 219)
```

In C#, without regard to LINQ, you check if a collection contains an item using code that reads "collection **contains** item"

```
myList.Contains(someId);
```

When you use `Contains` in LINQ that gets translated to SQL, LINQ provider translates one syntax to the other syntax to shield C# programmers from thinking about the differences.

Comment: When checking for a single ID in collection `myList.Contains(someId)` makes sense.

In this case though, I've got two collections, one for "persons" (a collection of person records from a table) and one for "PersonIDsWithThisPostcode" ( a collection of PersonIDs from a different table) so why is `PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.contains(some persons)` 
correct where 
`persons.contains(some PersonIDsWithThisPostcode)`
 is not?


What's the rule about which way round you're supposed to compare collections?

Comment: @Glyn Collections contain single items, not lists, so `myList.Contains(someOtherList)` does not make sense. You can ask if `myList` and `someOtherList` share items in common, or if one collection is contained entirely inside the other, but you would need to use a quantifier for that (`Any` or `All` methods correspond to ∃ and ∀ in math).

Comment: So "myList" is a collection?
Should I be able to use `myListA.Contains(myListB)` and `myListB.Contains(myListA)` interchangeably if all you're doing is returning common elements.
The person model is a collection isnt' it? PersonIDsWithThisPostcode is a collection because it's an IQueryable isn't it?

Comment: @Glyn `Contains` method is for collection-to-item checks, not for collection-to-collection operations for finding common elements. There's no such syntax as `myListB.Contains(myListA)` for finding common elements. You can use `myListB.Intersect(myListA)`, and that would give you another collection of items common to both sequences. You can then apply `Any` to it to see if the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: So how come `ps.PersonID.Contains(PersonIDsWithThisPostcode)` works?    If PersonID is a single item and PersonIDsWithThisPostcode is a collection isn't that item-to-collection, wouldn't if have to be `PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID)` to be collection-to-item?

Comment: @Glyn Single objects do not have `Contain` method, only collections do. So it has to be `PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID)`

Comment: Sorry, wrong end of the question. `PersonIDsWithThisPostcode.Contains(ps.PersonID)` if `ps.PersonID` is a single item, is it returning multiple rows because of the Lambda expression?